Xcode Cloud: No signing certificate Mac Development
I am getting the following error in Xcode Cloud:
/Volumes/workspace/repository/macos/Runner.xcodeproj: error: No signing certificate "Mac Development" found: No "Mac Development" signing certificate matching team ID "22649D52Q5" with a private key was found. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Below is my ci_post_clone.sh script
#!/bin/sh

# Fail this script if any subcommand fails.
set -e

# The default execution directory of this script is the ci_scripts directory.
cd $CI_PRIMARY_REPOSITORY_PATH # change working directory to the root of your cloned (cloud) repo.

# Install Flutter using git.
 git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git --depth 1 -b stable $HOME/flutter
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/flutter/bin"

# Install Flutter artifacts for iOS (--ios), or macOS (--macos) platforms.
flutter precache --macos

# Install Flutter dependencies.
flutter pub get

# Install CocoaPods using Homebrew.
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 # disable homebrew's automatic updates.
brew install cocoapods

# Install CocoaPods dependencies.
cd macos
pod deintegrate
pod update
cd ..
# Install Flutter dependencies.
flutter pub get
dart run build_runner build -d
# flutter build macos
flutter build macos --release 

I have tried clearing my keychain and revoking all certificates. Nothing seems to get past this error. I have automatic signing turned on in Xcode and the program compiles/runs fine in Xcode, just not Xcode Cloud online.

I think it may help if you tag this question with flutter. Is the action that fails an Archive action that's triggered as part of your Xcode Cloud workflow, or is it the command in your script flutter build macos --release?
